# what does the php operator " -= " do?

Tags: php, operator-keyword

Hi just a quick question on an operator i have not come across before, which i cant seem to find the answer for...

what does the -= operator do?

the context of the code is in a pagination script.

```
$page = $_POST['page'];
$cur_page = $page;
$page -= 1;
$per_page = 15;
$previous_btn = true;
$next_btn = true;
$first_btn = true;
$last_btn = true;
$start = $page * $per_page;
echo('start: '.$start.' - per-page: '.$per_page);
```

Comment: for `$page -= 1;` it's short for `$page=$page-1;` You could also do `$page--;` to decrement page by 1

Comment: Thats an excellent post but it dont think it answers my specific question i have already looked on the php site under the various operator groups and the -= operator i could not find, not does that link contain the specific -= operator...

Comment: thanks @Waygood, will put that in my notebook

Comment: It's mentioned under [`.=` Assignment Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php#40084) in the manual.

Answer (score 4):

The `-=` operator take the number stored in the variable and subtracts the number after the `-=` sign.

```
$page -= 1;
//SAME AS
$page = $page - 1;
//SAME AS
$page--;
//SAME AS
--$page;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example it takes away 1 from `$page` and reassigns it back to `$page`. But in general it subtracts the value to the right of the operand from the variable on the left and reassigns it.

it's equivalent to

`$page = $page - 1`

there's also the same for addition.

`$page += 1`

same as

`$page = $page + 1`